# We consider triangles with perimeter 1 and one of angles $120^o$

Tags: geometry

We consider triangles with perimeter 1 and one of angles $120^o$. Find the length of the sides of this triangle for which the area of the inscribed circle is the largest.

Let $\alpha = 2\pi/3$ and use the fact that $r=A/s=2A=2\cdot 1/2 \cdot b \cdot c \cdot \sin{\alpha}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}bc$. So we have to find how to maximise $bc$ while respecting the condition $a+b+c=1$ and the fact that it is a triangle. I don't know how to continue from here though.

Comment: Can you use calculus derivatives?

Answer (score 1):

Let $a$ be the side opposite to the $120º$ angle. Then, by the cosine law and knowing that $a = 1-(b+c)$, 
$$a^2=b^2+c^2-2bc\cos (\frac{2\pi}{3})=b^2+c^2+bc$$
$$\require{cancel}1-2(b+c)+\cancel{b^2}+2bc+\cancel{c^2}=\cancel{b^2}+\cancel{c^2}+bc$$
$$bc=2b+2c-1$$
$$b=\frac{2c-1}{c-2}$$

So we must find the maxima of $bc=\frac{c(2c-1)}{c-2}$, which are at $c=2\pm\sqrt{3}$, but only $c=2-\sqrt{3}<1$. Then, as expected because of the symmetry of the problem, $b=c=2-\sqrt{3}$ and $a=2\sqrt{3}-3$.

Comment: I don't understand why it must be b=c ??

Comment: If you substitute $c=2-\sqrt{3}$ in $b=(2c-1)/(c-2)$, you get that also $b=2-\sqrt{3}$ . I did no supposition about $b$ and $c$ being equal, it was found through calculation, but it's kind of logical: imagine the extreme cases where $a=b=0.5$, $c=0$ and where $a=c=0.5$, $b=0$. In both cases the inradius is 0 and it's logical that the biggest inradius will happen at the middle point, when $b=c$.